# Why doesn't my else statement run? [python]

Tags: python

```
cont = "y"

while cont == "y":
    day = input("Enter today's day: ")

    if day == "monday" or "Monday":
        day = day.upper()
        if day in my_class:
            print ("You have ",my_class[day], " today")

    elif day == "tuesday" or "Tuesday":
        day = day.upper()
        if day in my_class:
            print ("You have ",my_class[day], " today")

    elif day == "wednesday" or "Wednesday":
        day = day.upper()
        if day in my_class:
            print ("You have ",my_class[day], " today")

    elif day == "thursday" or "Thursday":
        day = day.upper()
        if day in my_class:
            print ("You have ",my_class[day], " today")

    elif day == "friday" or "Friday":
        day = day.upper()
        if day in my_class:
            print ("You have ",my_class[day], " today")

    else:
        print ("Enter a valid day")

    cont = input("Type y to continue: ")
```

I want it to print what the else says if an invalid date is put in but it skips over to printing "Type y to continue: "

Comment: The `or` statement is not doing what you think it is. Should be `if day == 'Monday' or day == 'monday'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your use of the `or` operator:

```
if day == "monday" or "Monday":
```

[Is translated as](https://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/python/boolean.html#evaluation-of-logical-and-comparison-operators-and-membership-operators) "is `day == "monday"` truthy, or is `"Monday"` truthy?" Since `"Monday"` is always truthy (since it is a non-empty string), you will always get this `if` block. Your ifs and elifs should look more like:

```
if day == "monday" or day == "Monday":
```

One way to shorten it would be:

```
if day in ["monday","Monday"]:
```

However, a cleaner way to do this same check would be:

```
if day.lower() == "monday":
```

This will make your check case insensitive. The rest of your `elif` statements should do the same.